# How to create a list in VB and later test against it

Tags: vb.net, list

I have seen somewhere before, where someone created a list like so:

```
Public List()
 Object1
 Object2
 Object3
 Object4
```

I do not remember it exactly, so I just pieced it from memory. But, they were then later to ctest another object against it: e.g.

`If Object3 = List Then` or `If List.Contains(Object/StringHere) Then`

Is there such a thing as this, or do I have it all wrong? I know how to create arrays, and lists of strings, but I can't remember how to create a list like this, and didn't know how to search for it. If this is a duplicate, please post the link to the original question, thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I need Option Strict to be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy sample ..

```
Dim a as New List(Of String)

a.Add("one")
a.Add("two")
a.Add("three")

MsgBox(Format(a.Contains("four")))
MsgBox(Format(a.IndexOf("two")))
```

Comment: I need Option Strict to be on, which is giving me all kinds of issues on other lists.

Answer (score 2):

It was probably `From`:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Something) From {
    object1,
    object2,
    object3,
    object4
}
```

And then yes, it’s

```
list.Contains(someObject)
```

If you have distinct objects and *only* need to test `Contains`, though, use a `HashSet(Of T)` instead!